# need to insert data all together into temp table

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

hi here is my sample code .

i need to insert the data from both the procedures all together rather than one after one..this code inserts the data 1st from the first procedure and then from the second with the row number that 1st has ended inserting.Please suggest a way by which i can insert the data all together and not sequentially.

```
create or replace package body help
as
procedure main_proc(param1 number,param2 number,v1 out number,v2 out number)
is 
v_resultset help.cursortype-->this is defined in the package spec
v_name varchar2(10);
v_code varchar2(40);

begin

v1:=param1;
v2:=param2;

proc1(v1,v_resultset);
LOOP
FETCH v_resultSet INTO v_name;
EXIT WHEN v_Resultset%NOTFOUND;
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Error in Proc1');
INSERT INTO temp_table(name) values(v_name) ;
END LOOP;

proc2(v1,v2,v_resultset);
LOOP
FETCH v_resultSet INTO v_code;
EXIT WHEN v_Resultset%NOTFOUND;
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Error in Proc2');
INSERT INTO temp_table(code) values(v_code) ;
END LOOP;

end main_proc;

proc1(v_name VARCHAR2,r_resultset out help.cursortype)
is
begin
open r_resultset for 
select name from emp where dept_id=2;
end;

proc2(v_name VARCHAR2,v_code VARCHAR2,r_resultset out help.cursortype)
is
begin
open r_resultset for
select code from code_table where dept_id=3;
end;

end help;
```

I need to insert the data all together instead of sequentially into my global temp table.

this procedure inserts data like below :
name     code

clark     (null)
jones     (null)
smith     (null) 
adam      (null)
(null)     001
(null)     002
(null)     003
(null)     004

whereas i want it to be inserted as

name     code
clark    001
jones    002
smith    003
adam     004

---

```
procedure packagecategory_info(p_item_cat number,p_item_sub_cat number,p_pack_cat_id number,package_sub_cat number,pc_Resultset out Master_Product_Report.cursortype)
is
begin
if p_item_sub_cat is null and p_pack_cat_id is null and package_sub_cat is null then
open pc_Resultset for
    Select Name From Packagecategory Where Itemcategory_Id in (select id from itemcategory start with id=p_item_cat connect by prior id=parent_id);
elsif p_pack_cat_id is null and package_sub_cat is null then 
open pc_Resultset for
Select Name From Packagecategory Where Itemcategory_Id In (Select Id From Itemcategory Where Parent_Id Is Not Null Start With Id=P_Item_Sub_Cat Connect By Prior Id=Parent_Id);
Elsif Package_sub_Cat Is Null Then
open pc_Resultset for
select name from packagecategory start with id=p_pack_cat_id connect by prior id=parent_id and level_id !=3;
Else 
open pc_Resultset for
select name from packagecategory where id=package_sub_cat;
end if;
End packagecategory_info;

----- Main procedure in which above proc would be called
create or replace 
package body Master_Product_Report as 
procedure Product_Report (p_item_cat number,p_sub_cat number,p_pack_cat_id number,p_pack_sub_cat_id number,p_pack_id number,v1 out number,v2 out number,v3 out number,v4 out number,v5 out number)
is 
----------
--some code--
packagecategory_info(v1,v2,v3,v4,v_resultSet);
Loop
Fetch V_Resultset Into V_Pack_cat_Name;
EXIT WHEN v_Resultset%NOTFOUND;
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Error in Proc2');
INSERT INTO MASTER_PRODUCT_TABLE(PACKAGE_SUB_CAT_NAME) values(v_pack_cat_name) ;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the data all together instead of sequentially"? It does not matter how data is stored in a table, the only that matters is how you order it during select.

Comment: SEE MY DATA IS COMING FROM DIFFERENT TABLES AND IT IS ALSO BEING FETCHED BY DIFFERENT PROCEDURES....SO INSTEAD OF DATA BEING DISPLAYED IN THE TABLE LIKE..................NAME->JONES ALEX CLARK AND THEN CODE IS INSERTED FROM THE 4TH ROW INSTEAD SHOWING IN FRONT OF THE NAMES.tHAT IS WAT I MEANT BY ALL TOGETHER.

Comment: You can combine two queries by UNION ALL. Also you don't need to use any cursors and stored procedures for this purpose. It can by done just by one statement.

Comment: well this is just a small code that i made in order to make it clear what exactly i want to do whereas it is a business requirement and the code is like 1500 LOC which can't be copied here.the data stored in the table has to be shown on the front end.The requirement can't be done by just simple union and joins  so it has to be stored in a proper way. hope u get what i m exactly looking for.

Comment: 'DISPLAYED IN THE TABLE' is incorrect. Data is displayed when you retrieve it. If you are talking about order of records the only way to influnce it is ORDER BY.

Comment: well iam getting what u r saying..lemme try that.thanks anyways :)

Comment: well what if i have to store the data from temp table into csv file.all i want is name     code

clark           
jones    
smith    
adam     
          001
          002
          003
          004
my procedure returns data like this  whereas i want it to be inserted into table like name     code
clark    001
jones    002
smith    003 
adam     004

Comment: Are queries guarantied to return the same number of rows for employees and codes? It's confusing that dept_id filter is different for in proc1 and proc2.

Comment: no its is not mandatory that it will return the same number of records from the both the procedures. I dont want the any correspondence between the data rather instead of inserting null it should insert the value retrieved

Comment: well the above procedure was just an example take dept_id to be something else so it gets clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I eventually got it right:

```
proc1(v1, v_names);
proc2(v1, v2, v_codes);
LOOP
FETCH v_names INTO v_name;
FETCH v_codes INTO v_code;
EXIT WHEN v_names%NOTFOUND;
EXIT WHEN v_codes%NOTFOUND;
INSERT INTO temp_table(name, code) values(v_name, v_code);
END LOOP;

close v_names;
close v_codes;
```

Note that equality of numbers of rows being returned by procs is up to you. If number of rows is greater than number of codes some employees won't be inserted into temp_table.

Comment: well now i face the problem that u mentioned -'Note that equality of numbers of rows being returned by procs is up to you. If number of rows is greater than number of codes some employees won't be inserted into temp_table.' :( what could be the solution for that

Comment: It depends on logic that you want for generating codes. You must fix query in proc2() in order it gives enough codes.

Comment: there is no way i can fix the query as the data is very huge and its a live application that will keep on running forever so data fixing is not an option. Please suggest if some alternative can be done or if any other structure i can use to insert data in the temp table for which every column doesnot have same no of records as previous or next column. I need urgent reply :(

Comment: create sequence my_codes;
insert into temp_table (name, code)
select name, to_char(my_codes.nextval, '00000000')
from emp where dept_id=2;
?

Comment: but i need to insert it through the cursor resultset the refcursor that i have used above

Comment: The solution for refcursor is given. It's now time to make cursor returning needed data. May be you should ask another question and provide more details because further discussion is not related to your original question.

Comment: well i can't share the code according to company's policy but i will tell the requirement.I have already made the cursor statement that is elaborated select statement with joins and other filter criteria to get the data i need...

Comment: the procedure when compiled alone gives me the required data...there are multiple procedures having different select statemnts for the cursors and i am calling these procedures in the main procedure in the package body.so my different procedures retuen different number of output i just need to insert them in the temp table but not like first result of proc1 and then of second i want it to be inserted simultaneously for which u provided the solution and which worked as well but it gives me data in the second column equal to the number of data in the first

Comment: whereas data in my second column is larger in number than the second.iam fine with returning nulls in the first column for which data is not available but my query returning maximum rows should insert all the records in its respective column irrespective of what other columns are retuning.

Comment: Change line 'EXIT WHEN v_names%NOTFOUND;' to 'IF v_names%NOTFOUND THEN v_name := NULL; END IF;', isn't it?

Comment: i really thank you for putting in your time in this but then there is an other problem i do not know which would be the procedure that would output the maximum number of records so which cursor i would exit i dont know? i know its bit complicated :/

Comment: also wen i run my anonymous block it takes endless time to complete and keeps on running..is it because of the if statement that i used?

Comment: and if i introduce that if statement there should be a boundary to which row it should insert null..i thought of the same earlier but then i am not able to find the max of different row counts

Comment: To count number of rows from cursor - iterate throughout it with counter. But you will consume cursor, and if you want to get records from cursor you will have to open it again. There's no way to get number of records because even DB doesn't know it.

Comment: The main problem is that I can't really understand what logics you want to implement. Yes, you have described what you want to do but I have no idea how it could be useful in some production environment. I believe there is much pretty way (and with better performance) to do your task if you refactor application a little.

Comment: yes i understand.basically this is required for reports generation.suppose if i have a 4 packages related to sim card today i could have 5 more tommorrow so there is no way  i can restrict it rather than taking my output in loop.

Comment: see i have shared a part of my code...i hope u understand what exactly i am asking for...this report has to be generating whatever information is present till the time user runs it...and if some user runs it some other point of time there would be more enteries in db and then it has to generate result for that. So how can i restrict number of rows and taking the cursor at starting and then embedding all fetch into it is also resulting in constant running status of script output.

Comment: there are many procedures like the one i have shared every porcedure giving different output suppose if i have 5 packages then in other procedure related to that package there could be n no. of package categories...so watever is under a particular package i ave to output that info in different column in the same temp table

Comment: application has many heirarchies so data is also present in that way

Comment: woho!!! y did we write that loop without exit it went in infinite loop and now it inserted some 7 crore null recods in the table o_O thank you anyways